# Update value for the same table using parent, child condition in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have one table in DB2 which having parent & child relation on same table, how can I update child  column using parent relation.

Example:

```
update table1 
set    col1 = (select col2 from table2 where id='14') 
where  table1.id=table2.parent
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have specified your conditions jumbled around. I'm assuming you want to change the value of col1 on row 14, and you want it to have the value from col2 of its parent.

So the outer statement, the UPDATE, should have a WHERE clause specifying which row to update -- the one with id = 14.  When we refer to this reference to the table, we'll use a nickname for it. I chose a single letter nickname, 'u', to mean the row we're going to update.

I'm guessing the id column is numeric, in which case it should not be quoted. (The u qualifier there on id is optional, since there is no ambiguity in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement. I merely added it for clarity.)

The value that will be put in col1, comes from col2 in the subquery. We want to get it from the row whose id matches the parent column in the row to be updated. This record is also in table1, but to distinguish this table reference from the other, I'll give it a nickname of 'p', to mean parent row.

```
update table1 as u
  set col1 = (select col2 
                from table1 as p
                where p.id = u.parent
             )
  where u.id = 14
```

---

( *I've used the word "nickname", but the proper term is "correlation name".* )